Elastic agent on AKS does not collect kubernetes total node memory metric
Issue
In my case, the Kubernetes dashboard (Metrics Kubernetes Node) does not show Memory usage visualization.
Context:
I deployed ELK stack 8.12.2 on Azure Kubernetes Service to monitor basic metrics of Node and Pod with pre-built dashboards from Kubernetes integration.
Troubleshooting
Issue
In my case, the Kubernetes dashboard (Metrics Kubernetes Node) does not show Memory usage visualization.
Context:
I deployed ELK stack 8.12.2 on Azure Kubernetes Service to monitor basic metrics of Node and Pod with pre-built dashboards from Kubernetes integration.
Troubleshooting
I found that the metrics kubernetes.node.memory.allocatable.bytes is not available on Elasticsearch.
I found that the metrics kubernetes.node.memory.capacity.bytes is not available on Elasticsearch.
The other kubernetes.node.memory.* are available like: kubernetes.node.memory.usage.bytes, kubernetes.node.memory.available.bytes,...
I found couple of limitation from official document as Important notes
Question
The other kubernetes.node.memory.* are available like: kubernetes.node.memory.usage.bytes, kubernetes.node.memory.available.bytes,...
I found couple of limitation from official document as Important notes
Question
Is  kubernetes.node.memory.usage.bytes an alternative metric for kubernetes.node.memory.allocatable.bytes on AKS?

Hope I understood your question clearly, kubernetes.node.memory.usage.bytes is not an alternative metric for kubernetes.node.memory.allocatable.bytes on AKS. kubernetes.node.memory.usage.bytes measures the amount of memory used by the node, while kubernetes.node.memory.allocatable.bytes measures the amount of memory that can be allocated to pods on the node. These are two different metrics with different meanings.

If you do not have kubernetes.node.memory.allocatable.bytes but you do have the total capacity (kubernetes.node.memory.capacity.bytes) and the current usage (kubernetes.node.memory.usage.bytes), you could estimate the allocatable memory. Kubernetes reserves a certain amount of system resources based on its configuration (kubelet configs like system reserved, kube reserved, and eviction thresholds). If you know these configurations, you could subtract them from the total capacity to estimate the allocatable memory.

But why so much hassle? Why not use the Azure AKS monitor to monitor the node memory metric.

Consider to aks sys-admin questions (e.g. monitoring questions) on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.


Is kubernetes.node.memory.usage.bytes an alternative metric for
kubernetes.node.memory.allocatable.bytes on AKS?

No, As discussed in comments, kubernetes.node.memory.usage.bytes is not an alternative metric for kubernetes.node.memory.allocatable.bytes on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). These two metrics have different purposes:

kubernetes.node.memory.usage.bytes measures the actual memory used by the node, including system overhead and pod consumption.
kubernetes.node.memory.allocatable.bytes measures the amount of memory available for pods after reserving system-level resources.

To estimate kubernetes.node.memory.allocatable.bytes when it’s missing, you can use the node’s total capacity (kubernetes.node.memory.capacity.bytes) and subtract the system reservations (e.g., kubelet configurations such as system reserved or kube reserved). This estimation provides an approximation but may not be as precise as the actual metric.
Tracking memory metrics in Azure Kubernetes Service can be done effectively using monitoring tool - Azure Monitor where -   you can use the "Metrics" section in the Azure portal to view node-level memory metrics or you can create custom alerts based on specific memory metrics like allocatable or usage bytes.

